# Need with Jolt Spec for dynamic key

Tags: jolt

My input looks like below

```json
{
  "honda" : {
    "accord" : [ "30", "20" ],
    "plus" : [ "20", "10", "" ]
  },
  "tesla" : {
    "modelY" : [ "50", "20", "" ],
    "modelX" : [ "20", "" ]
  }
}
```

I want to write a spec to get only the first value in the array for each model. This is dynamic data and may vary depending on the query. The output must look something like this. I have tried an no luck with the dynamic key.

```json
{
  "honda" : {
    "accord" : "30",
    "plus" : "20"
  },
  "tesla" : {
    "modelY" : "50",
    "modelX" : "20"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this spec,

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0": "&2.&1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```